# PXE boot with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, pxe

I'm currently having a PXE server to perform many different OS' installation over the network.

I have a fully functionnal Ubuntu 13.10 live environnement and I would like to give a try on 14.04 (using latest daily image).

But with 14.04, using exactly the same directory structure and access rights, same pxelinux.cfg/default file entry (see below) the boot hangs and stops with a kernel panic error

Any ideas? I almost searched, googled everywhere without finding any clue...

My pxelinux.cfg/default file:

```
LABEL Ubuntu 13.10 Live    
KERNEL images/ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi
APPEND boot=casper vga=normal rootfstype=nfs netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.XX.XX:/volume1/tftpboot/images/ubuntu fetch=tftp://192.168.XX.XX/tftpboot/images/ubuntu/casper/filesystem.squashfs ramdisk_size=1048576 debian-installer/language=fr console-setup/layoutcode=fr console-setup/variantcode=oss quiet splash initrd=images/ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz --

LABEL Ubuntu 14.04 Live
KERNEL images/ubuntu14/casper/vmlinuz.efi
APPEND boot=casper vga=normal rootfstype=nfs netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.XX.XX:/volume1/tftpboot/images/ubuntu14 fetch=tftp://192.168.XX.XX/tftpboot/images/ubuntu14/casper/filesystem.squashfs ramdisk_size=1048576 debian-installer/language=fr console-setup/layoutcode=fr console-setup/variantcode=oss quiet splash initrd=images/ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz --
```

Thanks in advance for your thoughts (and solutions with a little luck)

Comment: Can you please reopen the question since now 14.04 is out... It's not off topic anymore and I still have the issue with the latest release

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04, I expect that you need to use `initrd=images/ubuntu14/casper/initrd.lz` not `initrd=images/ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz` which is apparently the U13.04 RAMDisk. Wrong RAMDisk should raise similar error (a kernel panic error). Could you please verify that it is not just a typo mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
LABEL ubuntu 14.04_x86_64 
        MENU LABEL Install Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
        KERNEL http://10.1.34.245/pxe/images/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/vmlinuz.efi
        APPEND vga=normal boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=10.1.34.245:/var/nfs/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64 initrd=http://10.1.34.245/pxe/images/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/initrd.lz ip=dhcp  --
```

`ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` is mounted on `/var/nfs/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64`

and the following line in `/etc/exports`:

`/var/nfs/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64 *(no_root_squash,ro,async,insecure)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after waisting *hours* i got this running:

Unpacked and copied pxelinux.0 from an ubuntu 14.04.2 netboot.tar.gz image

Mounted the ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso image in /mnt/loop
    mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso /mnt/loop

copied vmlinux and initrd from the mounted iso image

```
cp /mnt/loop/casper/vmlinuz.efi /srv/tftp/needed_files/
cp /mnt/loop/casper/initrd.lz /srv/tftp/needed_files/
```

I started nfs with these options in /etc/exports:

/mnt/loop *(no_root_squash,ro,async,secure)

Then, finally, I could succesfully run this /srv/tftp/pxelinux.cfg/default file:

```
DEFAULT Ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64

LABEL Ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64
    MENU LABEL Install Ubuntu 14.04.2 (64-bit)
    KERNEL needed_files/vmlinuz.efi
    APPEND vga=normal boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.98.1:/mnt/loop initrd=needed_files/initrd.lz --
```